# I'm getting this error with vue router vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting this error: `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

I made sure the Vue router is properly installed.

routes.js

```
import Login from './views/Login.vue';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    routes:[
        {
            path:'/',
            name:'home',
            component:Home
        },
        {
            path:'/login',
            name:'Login',
            component:Login
        }
    ]
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'App',
 
}
</script>

<style >

</style>
```

Login.vue

```
<template>
   <div class='login'>
    <h3>Sign in</h3> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br> 
    <button>Connection</button>
   <p>You don't have an account? Sign up</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'login',
  data(){
      return {};
  },
  methods:{}
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.login{
  margin-top:40px;
}
input{
 margin:10px 0;  
}
button{
  margin-top:20px;
  width:10%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
p{
  margin-top:40px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
p a {
  text-decoration:underline;
  cursor: pointer;

}
</style>
```

Comment: could you share your main.js file please?

Comment: it looks like you need to import and declare <router-view/> component in your app.vue

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the component named `Home` instead of `App`? You show the code for the `App` component but not for `Home` so i don't really know what the problem